# How to explicitly set last_row and last_column in Roo::Excelx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, roo-gem

i am having a excel sheet with raw data as below screenshot:

[image]

when i am calling 'last_row' method it will return 11th row (b'coz data exist in D,E,F columns),and last_column it will return 6, but i want data of only A,B and C columns and don't want to loop up-to 11th row and 6th column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
last_row_number = xlsx.last_row
required_values = []
"A".upto("C") do |column|
  required_values << xlsx.cell(last_row_number, column)
end
```

required_values will be an array of cell values of 11th row and 'A', 'B', 'C' columns